# Error al añadir las barras de error y el valor medio aun gráfico de barras apiladas

Tags: r

Estoy intentando realizar una gráfica de barras apiladas junto con barras de error y el valor del porcentaje total.

Para ello he cogido el set de datos que adjunto en este link (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10JX89O5-lxmpIeSgq4l8A68DrdogbWEk/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=110212220745254658348&rtpof=true&sd=true) y he corrido el siguiente código:

```
  ggplot(TOTAL, aes(x = estudio, y = per, fill = Grados_GOLD)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 25, 10),
                       labels = scales::percent_format(scale = 1),
                       limits = c(0, 25))+
    geom_text(aes(x=estudio, label=valor, y=per, fill=NULL), vjust=-0.25) + 
    fill_palette(palette = "Dark2")+
    labs(x = "", y="Percentage (%)",face = "bold")  +
    theme(text = element_text(size = 20),
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust=1, face = "bold"),
          panel.background = element_blank(),axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
          legend.title=element_blank(),
          legend.text = element_text(face="bold"),
          axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold"),
          axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold"))+
    geom_errorbar(aes(x=estudio, y = per, ymin=per-sd_min, ymax = sd_max-per), inherit.aes = FALSE,
            position=position_dodge(.9))
```

Obteniendo la siguiente figura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las barras de error y el valor total aparecen multiples veces. Me gustaría saber como poner las barras de error sin dubplicaciones y justo en la parte de arriba poner un único valor total.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En base a la pregunta, no me queda claro **cual es el resultado esperado**, ya que tienes varias etiquetas y barras de errores. Me explico:

```r
    library(readxl)
    TOTAL <- read_excel("Libro1.xlsx")
    
    TOTAL[c("Grados_GOLD", "estudio", "valor")]

#> # A tibble: 20 x 3
#>   Grados_GOLD estudio                    valor                 
#>   <chr>       <chr>                      <chr>                 
#> 1 Leve        Episcan I (40-80 yrs old)  12.1% (9.23% -11.15%) 
#> 2 Leve        Episcan II (40-80 yrs old) 15.4% (11.2% -12.53%) 
#> 3 Leve        IBERPOC                    21.7% (20.66% -23.23%)
#> 4 Moderado    Episcan I (40-80 yrs old)  12.1% (9.23% -11.15%) 
#> 5 Moderado    Episcan II (40-80 yrs old) 15.4% (11.2% -12.53%) 
#> 6 Moderado    IBERPOC                    21.7% (20.66% -23.23%)
#> 7 Muy severo  Episcan I (40-80 yrs old)  12.1% (9.23% -11.15%) 
#> 8 Muy severo  Episcan II (40-80 yrs old) 15.4% (11.2% -12.53%) 
#> 9 Muy severo  IBERPOC                    21.7% (20.66% -23.23%)
#>10 Severo      Episcan I (40-80 yrs old)  12.1% (9.23% -11.15%) 
#>11 Severo      Episcan II (40-80 yrs old) 15.4% (11.2% -12.53%) 
#>12 Severo      IBERPOC                    21.7% (20.66% -23.23%)
#>13 Leve        Episcan I (40-69 yrs old)  7.7% (6.83% -8.69%)   
#>14 Leve        Episcan II (40-69 yrs old) 8.8% (8.16% -9.49%)   
#>15 Moderado    Episcan I (40-69 yrs old)  7.7% (6.83% -8.69%)   
#>16 Moderado    Episcan II (40-69 yrs old) 8.8% (8.16% -9.49%)   
#>17 Muy severo  Episcan I (40-69 yrs old)  7.7% (6.83% -8.69%)   
#>18 Muy severo  Episcan II (40-69 yrs old) 8.8% (8.16% -9.49%)   
#>19 Severo      Episcan I (40-69 yrs old)  7.7% (6.83% -8.69%)   
#>20 Severo      Episcan II (40-69 yrs old) 8.8% (8.16% -9.49%)
```

Ahí podemos ver que se duplican las etiquetas porque hay varias. En tu `geom` a cada una le asignas `aes(..., y = per)`, que es un valor distinto para cada fila. Por eso se duplica. Pasa lo mismo con `geom_errorbar()`

Veo dos alternativas:

1. Crear un dataset de apoyo para las etiquetas y las barras de error, con las coordenadas que necesitas.
2. Hay otra alternativa, que es usar `aes(y=sd_max)` que es único por estudio. En la `geom_barplot` se puede hacer lo mismo usando `aes(y=mean)`. El inconveniente es que no consigo entender el gráfico que quieres obtener.

Te dejo un ejemplo con la alternativa 2) y su resultado:

```r
# Para adecuar el orden de las categorías a tu ejemplo
levels <- unique(c("IBERPOC", sort(TOTAL$estudio)))
TOTAL$estudio <- factor(TOTAL$estudio, levels = levels)


library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

ggplot(TOTAL, aes(x = estudio, y = per, fill = Grados_GOLD)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(
    breaks = seq(0, 25, 10),
    labels = scales::percent_format(scale = 1),
    limits = c(0, 25)
  ) +
  geom_text(aes(
    x = estudio,
    label = valor, y = sd_max, fill = NULL
  ),
  vjust = -0.25,
  check_overlap = TRUE
  ) +
  fill_palette(palette = "Dark2") +
  labs(x = "", y = "Percentage (%)", face = "bold") +
  theme(
    text = element_text(size = 20),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1, face = "bold"),
    panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    legend.text = element_text(face = "bold"),
    axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold"),
    axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold")
  ) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = estudio, y = mean, ymin = sd_min, ymax = sd_max),
    inherit.aes = FALSE,
    position = position_dodge(0.9)
  )
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Una solución limpia y funciona correctamente. Muchas gracias Diego